# text file transformation using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and I want to do the following text file transformation:

From

```
name1 sqlcmd -Sserver1 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt

name2 sqlcmd -Sserver2 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt

name3 sqlcmd -Sserver3 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt
```

to

```
name1

sqlcmd -Sserver1 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt

name2

sqlcmd -Sserver2 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt

name3

sqlcmd -Sserver3 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt
```

What is the easiest way?

Thank you!

Comment: SO rules ---  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)   What have you tried? Show us your code? Dhow any errors encountered.

Comment: If this is as simple as you show, then this is PowerShell beginner stuff, just using a text split on the name and send to a new file. It's OK to be new but at minimum some the time to get some training. Youtube is your friend. Just search for Beginning PowerShell, PowerShell text parsing, Powershell loops, PowerShell file and folder management, etc.

Comment: I know that is a simple question, but the list of file entries is quite long and should be done with a loop using foreach or get-content and I don't know how. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, but it does not matter how long the list is, but it is just Get-Content and split on the name of the first space in the string in a ForLoop. See the example I left for you done in the PowerShell ISE< but you can do this in VScode, or whatever other Powershell editor you have or in the console host. Yet, normally you should show your code, otherwise, you are asking folks to do your work for you. That is really not a thing here.  Ever so often as I'll do here, if it is interesting to them (this one is not). Yet, if you don't show effort, you will get donwvoted, and closed. Just say'in...

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment to you...

```
# Create a new file using sample data
@'
name1 sqlcmd -Sserver1 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt
name2 sqlcmd -Sserver2 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt
name3 sqlcmd -Sserver3 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt
'@ | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Scripts\MySampleData.txt'

# View the new file in the ISE editor pane
psEdit -filenames 'D:\Scripts\MySampleData.txt'

<#
Read the file content and loop to split on name string
Split on the first space, via -split operator and regex
#>

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Scripts\MySampleData.txt' | 
ForEach{$PSItem -split '\s', 2}

<#
# Results

name1
sqlcmd -Sserver1 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt
name2
sqlcmd -Sserver2 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt
name3
sqlcmd -Sserver3 -Uuser -Ppasswd -ifile.txt
#>
```